# passing values based on selection

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am working with angularjs. I have a table with data column which has hyperlink and when clicked in `<td>` data the 'prID' is passed to the URL as shown in the demo. But issue is for some of the rows in the table i have multiple prID's passed, when clicked on it, it is passing all the prID's instead i want to pass only one prID on which user mouse over and click on that ID.

DEMO:
https://plnkr.co/edit/sWbpovAT7II1eM4yRA2X?p=preview

example: For second row in the table i have values `2; 30; 21` . When user mouseover and click on it currently it is passing `2; 30; 21` in the URL instead i want to pass single value at a time. When user mouse over on 2 it should pass value 2 and when mouseover on 30, it should pass 30...This way i have couple of rows with multiple prIDs and the data is dynamic.

sample code:

```
<table border="1">
         <tr ng-repeat="data in dataInfo">
         <td><a href="http://myURL.com/getInfo/viewStatus?prInfo={{data.prID}}" target="_blank"> {{data.prID}}</a></td>
     </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: From three which one you want pass through link?

Comment: @Hanif - It depends on the user selection. If user want to see first prID info ,onclick on first value it should pass only first prID(i.e.,2). If user want to see second value info(i.e.,30) onclick on 30 it should pass value 30.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need nested loop when multiple ID on data.prID. Please try this way:

```
<tr ng-repeat="data in dataInfo">
   <td><span ng-repeat="link in data.prID.split(';')"><a href="http://myURL.com/getInfo/viewStatus?prInfo={{link}}" target="_blank"> {{link}}</a><span ng-if="!$last">;</span></span></td>
 </tr>
```

Comment: I want to show display ; between prID's so user can know that there are multiple prID's. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes, let me do it for you :)

Comment: I have updated my answer, also see here: https://plnkr.co/edit/bQU7YL9vD4IISZqRTg3Y?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code I've edited from Hanif

```js
// Code goes here

angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('DataCtrl', function ($scope) {

$scope.dataInfo = [
   {
     "prID": "1",
      "name": "Fight Club",
      "desc": "Brad"
    },
   {
     "prID": "2; 30; 21",
      "name": "Matrix (Series)",
      "desc": "Keanu Reeves"
    },
   {
     "prID": "33",
      "name": "V for Vendetta",
      "desc": "Hugo Weaving"
    },
    {
     "prID": "13",
      "name": "V for Vendetta",
      "desc": "Hugo Weaving"
    },
    {
     "prID": "111; 55",
      "name": "V for Vendetta",
      "desc": "Hugo Weaving"
    },
    {
     "prID": "3",
      "name": "V for Vendetta",
      "desc": "Hugo Weaving"
    }
  ];
  
  
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">
  <head>
    <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.5.0.js"></script>
    
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>

<div ng-controller="DataCtrl">
  
  <table border="1">
     <tr ng-repeat="data in dataInfo">
       <td>
         <a ng-repeat="link in data.prID.split(';')" href="http://myURL.com/getInfo/viewStatus?prInfo={{link}}" target="_blank"> {{link}}<span ng-if="$index+1 != data.prID.split(';').length">;</span></a>
        
       </td>
     </tr>
  </table>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

[Demo here](https://plnkr.co/edit/Nv4ietnrHJNc4ukNJBaT?p=preview)